# Why is concat not working with Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

having some issues with concatenating my array to an objects array for some reason. I've already found a work around, but I'm confused as to why this is happening. When I use "concat()" is just returns an empty array.

```
var ListType = {

    TextField: [],
    DateField: [],
    SignatureField: []

}

function GetCursorPosition(){
    Img = document.getElementById(Ite);

    var PosX = 0;
    var PosY = 0;
    var ImgPos;
    


    ImgPos = GetImageCoordinates(Img);
    PosX = event.pageX - ImgPos[0];
    PosY = event.pageY - ImgPos[1];
    
    Coords = [PosX,PosY];
    //console.log(Coords);
    var InputType = setRadioButton();
  
    CreateList(InputType, Coords);
}


function CreateList(InputType, Coords){

    if(InputType == "Text"){
        ListType.TextField.concat(Coords);
    }
    else if(InputType == "Date"){
        ListType.DateField.concat(Coords);
    }
    else{
        ListType.SignatureField.concat(Coords);
    }
    console.log(ListType.TextField);
}
```

When I use the "push()" method instead I get an array of arrays which isn't what I want so I tried using "concat()" and I just get "Array []". However, if i supersede the array and just push PosX and PosY I get what I want but it seems sloppy. Plus the whole point of this project is to learn website development and javascript so I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong. Also if you have a solution that i could implement please no JQuery, trying to learn javascript before I open that can of worms.

Comment: `array#concat` retuns a new array, rather than mutating an existing one. You need to do something like `ListType.DateField = ListType.DateField.concat(Coords)` at a guess

Comment: Unlike [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) doesn't change the array, it returns a new array with the new values. You should use  either `ListType.TextField = ListType.TextField.concat(Coords);` or `ListType.TextField.push(...Coords);`

Comment: The existing comments should address your issue. I want to add: if `x` and `y` are related, then you might want to keep them as a tuple and rethink your data structures (use an array of `[x, y]` tuples rather than a flat array of implicitly correlated value pairs).

Comment: Yep that's what I was missing appreciate y'all answering my question and explaining how concat actually works. Makes sense how you would have to set the object to the new array. Is there a way I can say a particular comment answered my question so others know.

Comment: Also, yeah I do agree with you jsejcksn. I'm just in the testing phase of my project and in the learning phase in general. So when I found this weird issue where concat wasn't working how I expected it I wanted to understand why. But later I'm going to add a way for the user to name certain coordinate pairs so I think I'll end up doing what you suggested.